# Pagination in WP query with transient API

Tags: wp-query, pagination, query, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I have integrated WordPress transient system with w3 total cache. Now I can`t to do pagination for this query.

```
<?php
  $paged1 = (get_query_var('paged1')) ? get_query_var('paged1') : 1;
  $recent1 = get_transient( 'recent1' );
  if ( false === $recent1) {
    $recent1 = new WP_Query ('cat=3&posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged1);
     set_transient('recent1', $recent1, 60*60);
  }
  // do normal loop stuff
  if ($recent1->have_posts()) : while ($recent1->have_posts()) : $recent1->the_post();
?>
<div id="line">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink () ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <h2><?php the_title (); ?></h2>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100), array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
    <?php the_advanced_excerpt(); ?>
  </a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: How do you set `'paged1'`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$paged1 = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried. It is work but there is a problem. Sometimes on page/2 there is content of page/1 or on the contrary. It seems caches sometimes confused. How to set they right ?)